# Covering Index from HELL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexing, include

I'm trying to build my DBA skills, but am really a SQL developer.  I've come across a set of tables (the most frequently used in the company) that are very wide and a non-sql person at some point in the past has created a non-clustered index with a key of:

Status (varchar(20)) that only has 6 possible values,

and Active (bit)

and then put every (70ish) field in the table in the INCLUDE clause.

My mind is a little blown by this.

My question is, what effect does this have?  I have to make a case to my superiors for removing it.

I guess someone thought that doing this you could get every active record of a given status without having to go to the leaf(?) level.

I'm thinking due to the very low cardinality it would always do an index scan (SYS.DM_DB_INDEX_USAGE_STATS shows an equal number of user_seeks and user_scans), and you'd have to update it constantly.

This is just such a bizarre way to build an index I can't guess all the negative side effects it would have.

I'm also hoping to get a better feel for the disadvantages of wide keys (but this isn't really the key is it)

Comment: Try some queries and see if it's actually even using that index.

Comment: Doesn't the fact that SYS.DM_DB_INDEX_USAGE_STATS shows values (7646 and 7647) for user_seeks and user_scans indicate it's being used?  I don't know when/why it's doing seeks.

Comment: Querying by those two fields DOES result in a Index Seek.  Not what I expected.  I know our most common query does return all (or almost all) the fields in the row.  Is it NOT crazy to INCLUDE them all in the index?  It shows about 3 times as many updates as seeks (and the same number of scans as seeks)..

Comment: How many rows are in these tables? e.g. how big are they? How often is the data in them changed?  The large number of included columns is not a concern beyond the storage space and additional work to maintain it.  Depending on size/read/write activity, it may be a non-issue.

Comment: Does the table have a Clustered Index on it?  If so, what is the definition?

Comment: There are 1.8 million rows.  70 Fields.  avg_record_size_in_bytes = 503.  Updated 5 times more often than read.

Comment: The clustered index is (and IDNum is varchar(25)):  ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblAtlanta] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_tblAtlanta] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [IDNum] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
GO